# How to get a specific node in XML tree with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<words>
    <word>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Teacher</name>
    </word>
    <word>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Pitcher</name>
    </word>
</words>
```

And the following jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "sites.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('word').each(function(){

        ...

});
```

How can I get word with ID == 1?

This ajax function is inside another function (`getWord()` function). I want to get word with any ID and assign that value to a local variable of `getWord()` function.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can always resort to writing a custom filter.

```
$(xml).find("word").filter(function () {
  return $(this).find("id").text() == "1";
}).each(function () {
  console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have another question: How can I get the word returned in `getWord()` parent function.

Comment: @VansFannel: You can't. Put your next steps into the `success` callback.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(xml).find('word').each(function(){

       if(parseInt($(this).find('id').text()) == '1')
{

      // your logic here
}
});
```